# SUblimeText2 plugin for automatic CSS class creation?

Tags: html, css, plugins, sublimetext2

I was looking for some plugin that could easily generate a CSS statement from my HTML template. So The moment I create a DOM element, should be possible to generate a CSS statement   to access that DOM element.

Could be a simple one that just adds the whole DOM order from my outter element to the desire element. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding the same like you, if you know something, tell me please.

But you can try it:

http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/

I hope you can use it, @artdias90